# python multiprocessing child process trigger parent event or method

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to create a child process, then the child process will do some time consuming long time work which may never end.

What I want to do is when the child process finishes one step, it will trigger an event of the parent process or just call some functions.

Here is part of my script:

```
class WorkerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, port, addresslist, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.serialPort = port
        self.addressList = addresslist
        self.sch = SerialCommunication(self.serialPort, self.addressList)
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            self.sch.RegularLoadInfo()
            self.result_queue.put(self.sch.rawData)
            # here trigger event or method in parent process, or let the queue put trigger it

    def shutdown(self):
        try:
            self.sch.stopSerial()
        except Exception:
            print(Exception)
        self.exit.set()

class DataExchange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._serialOn = False
        self.workerSerial = None

    def get_serialOn(self):
        return self._serialOn

    def set_serialOn(self, value):
        self._serialOn = value
        if self.serialOn == True:
            result = multiprocessing.Queue()
            self.workerSerial = WorkerProcess(self.serialPort, self.addressList, result)
            self.workerSerial.daemon = True
            self.workerSerial.start()

        elif self.serialOn == False:
            self.workerSerial.shutdown()

    serialOn = property(get_serialOn, set_serialOn)

    def OnUpdate(self, event):
        # triggered by child process
        # do something
        pass
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a method in another process directly, but you have two possibilities:

### a) parent waits until child sends

You'll need to set up a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to communicate from the child to the parent (or a [`pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) if you need to communicate both ways) and then make the parent block (run `get()`) until the child sends data (runs `put()`).

Since you already have set up a queue `result` in your code you either want to take this or hand in another queue to the `__init__` constructor of `WorkerProcess`.

In the parent process do something like this:

```
        result = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.workerSerial = WorkerProcess(self.serialPort, self.addressList, result)
        self.workerSerial.daemon = True
        self.workerSerial.start()
        while True:
            event = result.get()
            if event is None:
                break
            if event == 'update':
                self.OnUpdate()
        self.workerSerial.terminate()
```

You'll need to define how the child communicates that he sent the last element (aka the "sentinel"), I chose `None` in the example code above.

Once the parent gets the sentinel, it runs `terminate()` on the child to end it.

### b) parent polls for changes

If the parent needs to do stuff alongside waiting for the result, you'll need to periodically check if there's stuff in your queue:

```
# do stuff in parent
if not result.empty():
    event = result.get()
    # process event as above and terminate if `None`
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to keep the parent responsible to another GUI button click event, so I think I cannot use the while loop in a). Another thing is the WorkerProcess will not stop unless it is told to, so the terminate may not proper here.

Comment: For b), I think it also needs a loop for it. So where can I put it if I need to keep the parent process always able to response to outside event?

Comment: it needs to be inside the GUI loop, if you want you can add the GUI loop bit to your question and I can try to work the if not `result.empty()` if block in

Comment: I use b) with a new threading.Timer. Even though this is not what I wish, but problem is solved. Thanks~